# YYMM Integer in a df to datetime object

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I got a Dataframe with the column "DOB", which is date of birth. It is formatted as an int with in the format YYMM. I need the datetime object of that.

```
df['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DOB'], format='%y%y%m%m') 
df['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DOB'], format='%y%m')
```

That didn't work.

I want to adjust all values in the column to the right datetime object, it doesn't matter if in the end theres a day in front of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a 4 digit ints as a column of a dataframe. You can convert to date time as follows:

```
dob = ['2007','1605','1709','1809','0605','0812']

df = pd.DataFrame(dob,columns=['DOB'])

for i in range(len(df['DOB'])):
    split_list = [df.DOB.loc[i][:2],df.DOB.loc[i][2:]]
    df['DOB'].loc[i] = '-'.join(split_list)

df['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DOB'], format='%y-%m')
```

The new dataframe has a column with type-datetime64[ns]. You can also extract the year and month separately as follows:

```
df['year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['DOB']).year
df['month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['DOB']).month
```

Now the final dataframe has 3 columns.One with the date, other with year and month.